# How to set style sheet from server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, stylesheet, server-side

I am using the style sheets for the gridview from this link

http://www.cyberslingers.com/Sandbox/GridView.aspx

It has various style sheet attached to the same gridview. What I want to attach the style sheet from server side to the page when user select the drop down list item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to just put runat="server" id="myname" in your  tag, then you can set the value in code.

HTML

```
<link id="MyLink" href="~/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" runat="server" />
```

CS

```
MyLink.Href = "~/css/Different.css";
```

Comment: But I am not getting any property like MyLink.Href in server side. I have make sure that I am using runat="server" attribute.

Comment: I am able to see other attributes of MyLink like innerHTML, value... but not href.

Comment: Are you using .Net 1.1? This property was added in version 2.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h119cex2(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: You might also need to put a prefix on the link control like this <asp:HtmlLink id="MyLink" runat="server" />

Comment: @Martin I am using asp.net 3.5 and I tried to put <asp:HtmlLink into aspx page, but I didn't find any control like this also it is not having any property in it. VSS is showing error.

Comment: I'm stumped. This aught to "just work." The HtmlLink control is a standard part of the framework and Visual Studio knows all about it. You must have done something bizarre with your setup, or you are missing something simple, as such it is a bit hard to fix using comments on this post. I suggest you find a consultant that can sit down at your desk with you to help.

Comment: I think his problem may be that he was using a master-page and trying to put the <link runat="server" /> tag within a content place-holder control in a content page that refers to his master-page.  In that scenario, the server-side link control generated is an HtmlGenericControl rather than an HtmlLink and thus the Href property (among others) is missing.  Unfortunately, to get an actual HtmlLink control, you must have your server-side tag as a direct child of the <head /> element in the page, not indirectly contained within a place-holder control.

Comment: For further explanation of my previous comment, read the discussion at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/273683/contentplaceholder-inside-the-head-element-special-head-parsing-logic-no-longer-applies.

Comment: @EdGraham MS have that connect down as Closed as Fixed. Any idea what version of .Net you need to see the fix?

Comment: @MartinBrown -- it still hasn't been fixed, as of .NET 4.5.  I resolved it by using an Ugly Hack (TM).

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a stylesheet on the server side and attach it to the page using:

```
HtmlGenericControl style = new HtmlGenericControl("style");
style.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
style.InnerText = "p { color:red; }"; 
Page.Header.Controls.Add(style);
```

The code above can be inside the event handler of the selectionindexchanged event of the  dropdown, you can then generate all the styles you want and attach them to the page.

If you simply want to attach a reference to an external css file then you can do:

```
HtmlGenericControl link = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
link.Attributes.Add("href", "/styles.css");
Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

Comment: Do I have to provide the path like this ../CSS/stylesheet1.css ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use an HtmlLink control in the second example?